# Child custody jurisdiction

Tags: family-law

**Facts**

- Two parents have in force a child custody agreement (a/k/a Parenting Plan, PP) in U.S. state X.
- The PP stipulates shared residential time with their minor child between the parents per a specific schedule.
- PP contains no unusual provisions.
- Parent A violates the PP and moves the child out of state (to U.S. state Y).

**Question**

Under what circumstances (if any) can parent A ever obtain legal custody of the child without physically returning to court in state X?

*If the values of X and Y matter in the answer, feel free to choose (and specify) them for yourself.*

Comment: That would require a court in Y to rule in obvious conflict with the court in X.  That seems highly unlikely.

Comment: If it ever came to a ruling. Parent B could presumably produce PP to the Y court if A filed a custody action in Y.